# SpringBoot web socket server not responding

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was working on implementing web sockets in springboot, I followed the example spring has given in there docs, after connecting to socket I am not receiving any response back from the server. I tried separating my frontend from the spring boot application, i.e two applications running on different ports.
Controller-

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    @MessageMapping("/Hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public  Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message){
        return new Greeting("Hello, "+ HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()));
    }
}
```

Model classes-

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class HelloMessage {
    private String name;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Greeting {
    private String message;
}
```

configuration class-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry){
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp-endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry){
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topics");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
```

Frontend-

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080//stomp-endpoint');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('http://localhost:8080//topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body));
        });
    });
}
```

send method -

```
function sendName() {
    stompClient.send("http://localhost:8081/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({'name': $("#name").val()}));
}
```

Output I am getting -

[image]

I am getting `connected to server undefined` and not receiving the response back from server there is no error log or sysout in the springboot console as well.

As I connect to the socket it gets connected fine, but after sending the message I am not getting the response even the sysout also not working in the java code.
How can I resolve this issue !

Comment: Can you post the "send" method?

Comment: @katiforis sorry for the delay, I have added the send method in the code

Answer (score 0):

- if you use `stompClient.subscribe`,in the backend you should use `@SubscribeMapping` to receive
- you can try `stompClient.send('/app/Hello',{},'')`

Comment: thank you for the answer but it didn't worked for me, I replaced MessageMapping to SubscribeMapping but still got the same issue "no response from server", I have added the snapshot of it in the question will you please suggest me some other way to do it

Comment: try this: `hello` to `Hello`,may be case sensitive, change `http://localhost:8081/app/hello` to `/app/Hello`

Comment: Thank you @vishun, my error was in the path section, I have typed @SendTo("/topic/greeting") I have forget the "s" at the end @SendTo("/topic/greetings")